# Complex Numbers, Square, Conics

Tags: conic-sections

On the Argand diagram, $P$ represents the complex number $z$, and $R$ the number $\frac{1}{z}$ A square $PQRS$ is drawn in the plane with $PR$ as a diagonal If $P$ lies on the circle $|z| = 2$,

(I) Prove that $Q$ will lie on the ellipse whose equation has the form $\frac{x ^ 2}{a ^ 2} + \frac{y ^ 2}{b ^ 2} = 1$;

(II) Hence, specify the numerical values ​​for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: I tried.The complex number P is 2 * cos (t) + 2 * i * sin (t) for any t. 

The complex number R is 0.5 * cos (-t) + 0.5 * i * sin (-t) for any t. This is the behavior of complex numbers with respect to their inverses. 

The midpoint of the diagonal PR is 1.25 * cos (t) + 0.75 * i * sin (t) for any t. 

The diagonal QS would have the same midpoint and length as PR, and QS ^ PR.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon your start:

The difference between $P$ and the midpoint is: $\frac{3}{4}\cos t+\frac{5}{4}i\sin t$

If we multiple this by $i$ we get a complex number which has been rotated by $90^\circ$. That complex number is: $-\frac{5}{4}\sin t+\frac{3}{4}i\cos t$

Next add this to the midpoint to get $Q$: $\frac{5}{4}\cos t-\frac{5}{4}\sin t+\frac{3}{4}i\cos t+\frac{3}{4}i\sin t$

$$=\frac{5}{4}(\cos t-\sin t)+\frac{3}{4}i(\cos t+\sin t)$$

$$=\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}\cos\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}i\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

You should recognise this as the parametric form of an ellipse with semi-major radius of $\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and semi-minor radius of $\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Hence $a=\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and $b=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Note we could have multiplied by $-i$ for the $90^\circ$ rotation. This would have followed very similar steps and arrived at $Q$:

$$=\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}\cos\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}i\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Which would lead to the same $a$ and $b$.